# Sharepoint Survey

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can i add responses tot an SharePoint survey with C#.

It's easy to add an new item to the list, but the result is not stored.

This is my code so far:

```
SPList slist = web.Lists[_surveyListname]; 
SPListItem item = slist.Items.Add();

item[0].value = "My Answer";
item.update();
```

I think the problem is in the value field. I can't find witch itemfield i need. Who can help me?

Comment: Try using the GUID for the column, available in the URL when viewing the column settings

Answer (score 0):

See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467435.aspx

You need change item[0].value to item["column name"] = value;

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;

SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

item["Title"] = TextBox2.Text;
item["Stock"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
item["Return Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
item["Employee"] = TextBox5.Text;

item.Update();
}
```

Comment: This is just for adding a listitem, i know how that's working. I think my problem is more related to the survey model.